# How can I apply put one event listener of the other?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to get this effect, whereby, the img background color is white at initial and when it is hovered, it should be red. But when it is clicked, a function should be carried out and the img background color should stick to red. However, when the imge is clicked again, the style should be like the initial style, where when the mouse is hovered, the img background color is red and when it is not, it is white.

Hope you get the message clear, here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">            
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

            var img = document.getElementById('search'),
                search = document.getElementById('searchEngine');

            search.className = 'invisible';

            img.addEventListener('mouseover', makeRed);
            function makeRed(event) {
                img.style.backgroundColor = "red";
            }

            img.addEventListener('mouseout', makeWhite);
            function makeWhite(event) {
                img.style.backgroundColor = "white";
            }

            img.addEventListener('click', displaySearchField);

            function displaySearchField(event) {
                if (search.className == 'invisible') {

                    search.className = 'visible';

                    img.style.backgroundColor = "red";

                } else {
                    search.className = 'invisible';
                    makeWhite();

                }
            }
        });
    </script>
```

The problem is, the background color is just not staying red when it is clicked!

Update
I've now reached till here with your advices:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

var img = document.getElementById('search'),
    search = document.getElementById('searchEngine'),
    clicked = false;

search.className = 'invisible';

img.addEventListener('click', displaySearchField);

function displaySearchField(event) {
    if (clicked == false) {
        clicked = true;
        img.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        search.className = 'visible';
        console.log('You have clicked!');

    } else {
        clicked = false;
        img.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
            img.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        });


        img.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
            img.style.backgroundColor = "white";
        });

        search.className = 'invisible';

        console.log('You have unclicked!');
    }
}

});
```

Can someone please give me a lift at this final moment, I'm still not getting the desired effect...

Comment: it IS red... and when you leave it is turning white... like you code it ;) set a property or variable to a state like "clicked" and inside the makeWhite() function check if the state is set or not.

Comment: are you looking forward to do it only with Javascript ? there are better alternatives I reckon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simplify this greatly with the use of CSS, where you have a class (let's say "initial") and a separate class (let's call it "clicked"). You could use Javascript (jQuery is GREAT for this) to set the class to clicked or initial and use CSS to to make the background automatically white and set the hover color to red. This is far, far faster than doing it in JavaScript and is less CPU intensive as well. Using CSS to manage your colors like this is also more universally compatible across browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Bob Dill, your idea worked:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

var img = document.getElementById('search'),
    search = document.getElementById('searchEngine'),
    clicked = false;

img.className = 'hover';
search.className = 'invisible';

img.addEventListener('click', displaySearchField);

function displaySearchField(event) {
    if (clicked == false) {
        clicked = true;
        img.className = 'nohover';
        search.className = 'visible';            
    } else {
        clicked = false;
        img.className = 'hover';

        search.className = 'invisible';

    }
}

});
```

Answer (score 1):

As Bob says, you can use CSS `:hover` pseudoclass to do the hover part, and use script to toggle the background on click.

I've included some helper functions, but much of this can be done directly on DOM elements using the [HTML5 *classList* API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).

Using *classList* API:

```css
.blah {background-color: blue;}
img {background-color: red;}
img:hover {background-color: blue;}
```

```html
<img id="d0" onclick="this.classList.toggle('blah')" src="a.jpg" width=100 height=100>
```

Using DOM Core APIs

```js
// Check if el has className
function hasClass(el, className) {
  return el.className.split(/\s+/).indexOf(className) != -1;
}

// Add className to el
function addClass(el, className) {
  if (!hasClass(el, className)) {
    var classList = el.className.split(/\s+/);
    classList.push(className)
    el.className = classList.join(' ');
  }
  return el;
}

// Remove className from el
function removeClass(el, className) {
  var classList;
  if (hasClass(el, className)) {
    classList = el.className.split(/\s+/);
    classList.splice(classList.indexOf(className), 1);
    el.className = classList.join(' ');
  }
  return el;
}

// If el has className, remove it. Otherwise, add it
function toggleClass(el, className) {
  if (hasClass(el, className)) {
    removeClass(el, className);
  } else {
    addClass(el, className);
  }
}
```

```css
  .blah {background-color: blue;}
  img {background-color: red;}
  img:hover {background-color: blue;}
```

```html
<img id="d0" onclick="toggleClass(this, 'blah')" src="a.jpg" width=100 height=100>
```